# Stop GridPane Stretching Horizontally in ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, width, fxml

I'm Trying to creat form inside a gridPane by FXML where this form should have vertical scroll becuase content not fit with screen height. but content's width is Okey.for screen size, but after added this Grid Pane in Scroll Pane started to stretch in horizontaly. any Advice to fix this please?

```
<ScrollPane fitToWidth="false"  hbarPolicy="NEVER"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
<content> 
    <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" >
        <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@estoresurvery.css" />
        </stylesheets>
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints    hgrow="NEVER" /> 
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="20.0" valignment="CENTER"/>
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="5.0" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="15.0" valignment="CENTER"/>
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="2.5" valignment="CENTER" />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="7.5" valignment="TOP"  />
            <RowConstraints percentHeight="2.5" valignment="TOP"  />
        </rowConstraints>
        <children>
            <Button alignment="TOP_CENTER" styleClass="logoHeader" GridPane.columnSpan="12" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        </children>
        <children>
            <Text styleClass="howHelpTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="10" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1"> 
                SomeTEXT    
            </Text>
        </children>
        <children>
            <Text styleClass="fieldText" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="10" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2"> 
                SomeTEXT      
            </Text> 
        </children>
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="NameTxt" styleClass="txtBox" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="8" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        </children>
        <children>
            <Text styleClass="fieldText" GridPane.columnSpan="12" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4"> 
                SomeTEXT
            </Text>
        </children>
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="PhonelTxt" styleClass="txtBox" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="8" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        </children>
        <children>
            <Text styleClass="fieldText" GridPane.columnSpan="12" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="6"> 
                SomeTEXT     
            </Text>
        </children>
        <children>
            <TextField fx:id="EmailTxt" styleClass="txtBox" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="8" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        </children>
        <children>
            <Button onAction="#showModle" styleClass="agrrementTxt" text="SomeText" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="10" GridPane.halignment="center" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />    
        </children>
        <children>
            <Button styleClass="yesBox" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="9">
                SomeTEXT  
            </Button>
            <Button styleClass="NoBox" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="9">
                SomeTEXT 
            </Button>
        </children>
        <children>
            <Button onAction="#showThanksMessage" styleClass="NoBox" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="11">
                SomeTEXT
            </Button>  
        </children>
    </GridPane>
</content>
```

Comment: Surely you need `fitToWidth="true"` (not `false`) to fit the grid pane to the width of the scroll pane.

Comment: I did that not make any sence @James_D